# 400 bad request when doing ajax call with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, request, bad-request

I am doing the following `ajax request` with `jquery`:

```
escapeAllInputs("#my_edit_form");   
var paramlist = $("#my_edit_form").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1",
    dataType: "html",
    url: "myServlet?"+paramlist,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        alert("success");
        // here is some irrelevant code I run at success
    },
    error: function(data){
        showErrorDialog(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

*The request is supposed to be going to this Java class:*

```
public class myServlet extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {
...
doRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
   Logger.debugLog("myServlet got a request...");
  // process request data here
}
```

}

Unfortunately, I keep getting the **"400 bad request"** error. As you can see, I send the data over parameters inside the url. The list is very big (64994 characters). Is this what is causing the problem?

The request never reaches the servlet, since the Logger never writes anything to it's logfile (the Logger works fine and is tested).

When the error appears, the **"success: function(data)"** part is not called. I keep ending up inside the **"error: function(data)"** part of the code, but the data is empty.

Couldn't get more info about "data" than "typeof = object". `ShowErrorDialog` pops up a jquery-ui dialog which does not show anything. I suppose this is to be expected, since the request was somehow bad, therefore there is no data returned.

This error is dependant on what is inside `#my_edit_form` - when I delete some entries there, everything works fine. After adding new entries the error may or may not appear again.

Comment: the content type is irrelevant because it is default do not set it explicitly, instead you can use `application/json`.

Comment: also do you return any markup code from the backend if not you can remove it `dataType: "html",`.

Comment: I do return a url to be displayed in case of success.

I solved the problem just now by sending the data like this:

dataType: "json",
data: paramlist,
url: "myServlet",

I don't understand however, why this way works and the other way SPORADICALLY does not...

Comment: I was wrong, the following seems to solve the problem completely:
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: paramlist,
    url: "myServlet",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
    
    },
    error: function(data) {

    }
  });
}

I just don't understand, why is it like that?

Comment: because the `dataType:"text"` is the return type of your ajax call.

Comment: the old method worked some times and some times not. I cannot even say, that the new method will work always. 

So, overall, I conclude this: it is a better practice (in this case) to not set dataType and submit the data throw data: ... instead of url: "myServlet?"+ ...

Did I get it right?

Comment: `dataType` is the type of data you are going to get from the server that could be `html, json, script, text` etc.